# Modifying function args in Typescript with spread syntax

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use the Tuple spreading syntax in Typescript to remove these function overloads? The complication is that I need to remap the function args to new types.

```
type Type = TString | TNumber
type TString = { tag: 'string' }
type TNumber = { tag: 'number' }

interface Mapping {
  string: string
  number: number
}

type Remap<T extends Type> = Mapping[T['tag']];

// can I collapse these function overloads in to one?
function checkFn<R extends Type, A extends Type, B extends Type, C extends Type>(argTypes: [A, B, C], retType: R, fn: (arg0: Remap<A>, arg1: Remap<B>, arg2: Remap<C>) => Remap<R>): void;
function checkFn<R extends Type, A extends Type, B extends Type>(argTypes: [A, B], retType: R, fn: (arg0: Remap<A>, arg1: Remap<B>) => Remap<R>): void;
function checkFn<R extends Type, A extends Type>(argTypes: [A], retType: R, fn: (arg: Remap<A>) => Remap<R>): void;
function checkFn(argTypes: any[], retType: any, fn: any): void {}

const stringType: TString = { tag: 'string' }
const numberType: TNumber = { tag: 'number' }

checkFn([numberType, stringType, numberType], numberType, (arg0, arg1, arg2) => 42)
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F5YGVgCcCWA7A5lAPrAHICuAtgEYRoBQokK62eSA3lMAIY4BcUA5AGcmuflAC+deMXJU0UNh259+WWdTGSa2YNQBmnAMbQAspzBhmUVjShRhmXHwfNbUNZWp8PcmlvrQAEoQZOYAPDBQEAAeulgAJoKw8AB8ClBmFswA2jDZ-Fw4-AC6xQDcNDQA9FVQhpxYUACSdQD2ADbt5oLQwAAWED1QeiRYhsAYrY2tAG7U7a2ciVDYHK1QUxAA-DQjYxNTdQOGANYAYlhhgVGxEAlJcJAANFAAgjdxy48QLwBCH3cvvAXgBhAH3ZKQFIACk4aBw30EfGyrz+oOKLzQEGA3z4gReeiwfFh8IADHiQuFXikXnCcABGCmhMBhX40qB0gBMTPCIJSAEoFGlgsyrgK+DNWhh4hU9uNJo1DMdzpdrjFPg9gW9wUDnlB-urAZqoSSEfAkVAUX8MVAsTj4HiCUSoKbyVARVT2XTGe7KSy2YKEMK-WL+RKpTLdqN5YclRBThcrjrjT9tYaId8YXTEcjXja7bj3U7iXSeSzqYHg6LAuKoJLpbLowdFcqLqacxysCBsvnsYWGiBi52QGG6xHrFpDFNhPYRGbIHwYKhHCxrEpeAIXKIJDQp1gZz5qIWYKRPPJFIUVIe0JpKnGE1hodlr98Xlv56mX-AbV+9a7afC9IATgnKVlAAAsoE0EAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Variadic Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) for a less descriptive version) the answer is "yes":

```js
type Type = TString | TNumber
type TString = { tag: 'string' }
type TNumber = { tag: 'number' }

interface Mapping {
  string: string
  number: number
}

type Remap<T extends Type> = Mapping[T['tag']];

function checkFn<P extends Type[], R extends Type>(
  argTypes: [...P],
  retType: R,
  fn: (...args: { [K in keyof P]: Remap<P[K] & Type> }) => Remap<R>
): void {}


const stringType: TString = { tag: 'string' }
const numberType: TNumber = { tag: 'number' }

checkFn(
  [numberType, stringType, numberType],
  numberType,
  (arg0: number, arg1: string, arg2: number) => 42);
```

Comment: This is a perfectly appropriate answer. The only thing that it gives the runtime error `checkFn is not defined`, so I suggest removing `declare` and writing `{}` after void